# View packages of a Maven artifact

Tags: java, maven

Given a Maven artifact:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-jdk-http -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-jdk-http</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.19.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

How do I know what packages this artifact makes available?

For example, it makes

`org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.sun` available, but not

`org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.undertow`.

Answer (score 1):

It will be resteasy-jdk-http-3.0.19.Final.jar , expand the jar in eclipse IDE to know the packages

Answer (score 0):

Use dependency hierarchy in eclipse. It will list the hierarchy of the dependents